# Creating a logic function of a burglar alarm system for a bank

Tags: digital-logic, security

This is the problem from homework that I am stuck on:

> A burglar alarm system for a bank is to be operative only if a master
>   switch at the police station has been turned on. Subject to this
>   condition, the alarm will ring if the vault door is disturbed in any
>   way, or if the door to the bank is opened unless a special switch is
>   first operated by the security guard's key. The vault door will be
>   equipped with a vibration sensor that will cause a switch to close if
>   the vault door is disturbed, and a switch will be mounted on the bank
>   door in such a way that it will close whenever the bank door is
>   opened. Symbolize the above system as a logic function and construct
>   the corresponding logic diagram.

So, I created an outline to list the conditions and the actions:

**Conditions:**

- *A* = Master switch is turned on
- *B* = Vault door is disturbed in any way
- *C* = Vault door is opened
- *D* = Special switch is 1st operated by security guard's key

**Actions:**

- *W* = Burglar alarm system becomes operative
- *X* = Alarm rings
- *Y* = Switch closes
- *Z* = Switch mounts on bank door in such a way it will close the door

And here's the truth table:

\begin{array}{c c c c|c c c c}
   A
 & B
 & C
 & D
 & W
 & X
 & Y
 & Z \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{array}

It is the last three I am not sure about:

- What happens if the door is disturbed AND the special switch is first operated at same time?  Would the alarm still ring?
- Would the vibration sensor still be activated when the door is opened (i.e., what would happen if the door is open and is disturbed at same time)?

I am not very knowledgeable with how bank security system works, so it would be nice if anyone can explain about it.

Comment: Knowledge of bank systems isn't important.

Comment: Yay, a decent homework question that shows what you've worked on so far!

Comment: `Switch mounts on bank door in such a way it will close the door` is wrong. It really is `switch mounts on bank door in such a way that it will close (activate) when the door is open`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, take a step back a little from it first and look at the different parts of it.

What stimulus, ignoring the extra conditions, would make the alarm sound?  Simple:

1. someone tampers with the vault -OR-
2. someone opens the bank door.

Now, when would those stimuli cause the alarm to sound?  Again, simple - when the alarm is armed.  When is it considered armed?

1. when it has been switched on at the police station -AND NOT-
2. when the guard's switch has been activated.

So, if it is armed -AND- triggered, then sound the alarm.

So you have three truth tables.  Firstly the trigger:

A = vault, B = door, Q = alarm.

\begin{array}{c c|c}
A&B&Q\\
\hline
0&0&0\\
0&1&1\\
1&0&1\\
1&1&1\\
\end{array}
Then you have the armed table:

A = police station, B = guard's switch
\begin{array}{c c|c}
A&B&Q\\
\hline
0&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
1&0&1\\
1&1&0\\
\end{array}
And then you combine them together into the alarm sounding table:

A = triggered, B = armed
\begin{array}{c c|c}
A&B&Q\\
\hline
0&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
1&0&0\\
1&1&1\\
\end{array}

You could then combine them into one huge logic table if you wanted.

In boolean it could be expressed as:

\$(Vault + Door) · Station · ¬Guard\$